# Database Migration and model transformation languages

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, model-driven-development

I'm considering migrating a database from SQL server to PostgreSQL.

The proposed new Postges Database will have a slightly different design to the old SQL server model.

I heard about model transformation languages and thought they might be worth considering for this task.

I have used [TEFKAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tefkat) to a limited extent some years ago, but it did not strike me as being mature enough for this task (although that was many years ago).

But there are other options available like [ATLAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATLAS_Transformation_Language), which I have not used yet.

Are there any model transformation languages out there that would be suitable? 
Or is this whole model transformation stuff the wrong way to go about this?

Comment: I should note that this is an entirely new project so I'm not  restricted to using Java. Any Model transformation library for any language is of interest to me.

Comment: Not sure it's what you're after but MDriven (formerly ECO) from CapableObjects has the ability to "wrap" an existing schema as a UML model. I've never used that feature, so I don't know if it has the ability to derive the UML model from the schema, or if you have to create the model from scratch yourself, and get some help with mapping it to the existing schema. Anyway, once that's done, it would be easy to switch to any other supported database, and I'm pretty sure both SQL Server and PostgreSQL are supported.